# Sorting elements of many fields

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, data-structures

If I have a vector , which is a dynamic array , that has many elements of a class type. Which means that every element has many data members. How can I sort that vector according to a specified data member in ascending order using the built-in sort function in c++? Or do I have to implement it by myself in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::sort and specify its comparison function. If you have the following class:

```
class ExampleClass{
public:
    int A;
    int B;
};
```

You can sort a vector of these classes using A by doing the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::sort(exampleVector.begin(), exampleVector.end(), [](const ExampleClass& lhs, const ExampleClass& rhs){
    return lhs.A < rhs.A;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) has an optional parameter for user-defined comparison function. If your class was `People`, and you wanted to sort based on `height`, your comparison function would be:

```
heightComp(Person a,Person b){
    return (a.height > b.height)
} //sorts in asc
```